# jquery ui no selected tab - show static content then tab content when tab selected

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Here is what I have so far...I'm trying to have a user come to a page where no tabs are selected but they are present on the page. When no tabs are selected I want the main page content to show. When a tab is selected I want the main page content to hide and the tab content to show for the appropriately selected tab.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if(location.hash) {
        $('#tabs').tabs();
        $('#campaigns').hide();
    } else {
        $('#tabs').tabs({
            selected: -1
        });
        $('#campaigns').show();
    }
});
```

My HTML is no different then the proper UI Tab procedure. I simply added another below that content with the id #campaigns.

Comment: You can do that for example you have 5 tabs and you will have 6 divs.
1 div is loaded when the page is loaded and the rest 5 divs is each for tab.
You can do something like this : 
<ul class="tabs"><li data-tab="first"/><li data-tab="second"/>...</ul>
<div class="content">
<div class="main"></div>
<div class="first hidden"></div>
<div class="second hidden"></div>...</div>
JS: $('ul.tabs li').click(function(){
   var tab = $(this).data('tab');
   $('.content').find('div').addClass('hidden').find(tab).removeClass('hidden');
});

Comment: Not exactly what I'm looking for...I already have the tabs showing up as not selected when the user first comes to the page by having selected be "-1". All I need is for the #campaigns div to disappear once one is selected.

Comment: You can do something like this, detect a click on li,Once tab is clicked , you can hide campaigns.
$('#tabs ul li').click(function(){
 // Hide Campaigns..
});

Comment: I'm using jQuery UI and for some reason your solution does not work with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can bind a `tabsselect` event to tabs and use it to hide the extra div

```
$("#tabs").bind("tabsselect", function (event, ui) {
   $('#campaigns').hide();
});
```

Comment: That hasn't worked either...but am glad you showed me that. It's got me headed in the right direction I'm sure. I don't know why jQuery UI won't allow that...but I'm sure it's something easy that I'm overlooking. Thanks so much for the help.

Comment: Not sure why this was closed. UmairP was able to help me so the question must not have been that "ambiguous, vague etc etc"